# jquery image hover effect of description

Tags: jquery, html, css

I currently have 4 images inline on an html page, that are pictures of people. I would like to know how to make an hover effect on the images (jQuery) so that when the mouse hovers above, the bottom of the page extends and a paragraph description of that person appears under all the images.

I would like to do it with this HTML

```
  <div class="page2">
    <a name="team" class="smoothScroll"></a>
    <h2>Meet the Team</h2>
    <div class="firstline">
    <div class="st">
        <ul>

        <li>
            <img src="bob.jpg">
            <p>Bob</p>
        </li>

        <li>
            <img src="bob.jpg">
            <p>Bob</p>
        </li>            

        <li>
            <img src="someone.jpg">
            <p>Someone</p>
        </li>   

        <li>
            <img src="someone.jpg">
            <p>Someone</p>
        </li>

        </ul>

        </div>




        <div class="nd">
        <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="bob.jpg">
            <p>bob</p>
            </li>
        <li>
            <img src="bob.jpg">
            <p>bob</p>
            </li>
        <li>
            <img src="someone.jpeg">
            <p>someone</p> </li>

        </ul>
        </div>

        </div>
```

CSS

```
.st img {
    max-height: 150px;
    max-width: 240px;

}
.st li {
    padding: 30px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}

.nd img {

    max-width: 250px;

}
.nd li {
    padding-left: 125px;
    padding-bottom: 80px;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
}


.firstline p{
    display: none;
}

img:hover + p{
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Using your code, you don't need jQuery at all. You can just target the sibling `p`:

```
p{
   display: none;
}

img:hover + p{
   display: block;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE 3**](http://jsfiddle.net/c471ezda/2/)

---

**PREVIOUS:**

You can do this with CSS as long as the images and their descriptions are siblings or descendants:

**HTML**

```
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<div class="content person1">
    <p>Person 1</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content  person2">
    <p>Person 2</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content  person3">
    <p>Person 3</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content person4">
    <p>Person 4</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content{
    display:none;
}

img:nth-of-type(1):hover ~ .person1{
    display: block;
}

img:nth-of-type(2):hover ~ .person2{
    display: block;
}

img:nth-of-type(3):hover ~ .person3{
    display: block;
}

img:nth-of-type(4):hover ~ .person4{
    display: block;
}
```

[**CSS EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c471ezda/)

## **OR**

If you really want to do this with jQuery there are several ways to do it. This is one:

**JS**

```
$("img").hover(function(){
   var grabClass = $(this).attr("class");
   $(".person-"+grabClass).toggle();   
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="one" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img class="two" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img class="three" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<img class="four" src="http://www.placecage.com/100/100"/>
<div class="content person-one">
    <p>Person 1</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content  person-two">
    <p>Person 2</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content  person-three">
    <p>Person 3</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
<div class="content person-four">
    <p>Person 4</p>
    <p>blah blah blah blah blah blah blah blah </p>
</div>
```

[**JQUERY EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c471ezda/1/)

Comment: Hi, In my CSS, when I add the code, the text dosent appear on hover
p{
    display: none;
}

img:hover + p{
    display: block;
}

Comment: @VibhasVatve can you post your CSS in your question above

Comment: @VibhasVatve it works fine when i put it in a fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/n7v8fyan/](http://jsfiddle.net/n7v8fyan/)

Comment: I see, however, if I simply write the css code as p { ......}, all the P elements go away. When I try to target only the P element in the div "firstline", it dosent work

Comment: right that was just my example, you can drill down like this: `.st ul li p{display:none;}`

Comment: Yes I see. However, I does not work when I have a h4 element showing the name of a person then a hidden p element underneath it, like so :
<li>
                <img src="someone.jpg">
                <h4>someone</h4>
                <p>jnjn</p>
            </li>

Answer (score 0):

Ok so first

```
<div class="page2">`
<a name="team" class="smoothScroll"></a>`
<h2>Meet the Team</h2>'
<div class="firstline">
<div class="st">

    <li>
        <img src="bob.jpg">
         <ul> //Add a ul
             <li>Bob</li> //Change these to li
         </ul>
    </li>

    <li>
        <img src="bob.jpg">
        <ul>
            <li>Bob</li>
        </ul>
    </li>            

    <li>
        <img src="someone.jpg">
        <p>Someone</p>
    </li>   

    <li>
        <img src="someone.jpg">
        <p>Someone</p>
    </li>

    </ul>

    </div>




    <div class="nd">
    <ul>
    <li>
        <img src="bob.jpg">
        <p>bob</p>
        </li>
    <li>
        <img src="bob.jpg">
        <p>bob</p>
        </li>
    <li>
        <img src="someone.jpeg">
        <p>someone</p> </li>

    </ul>
    </div>

    </div>
```

So basically you would do that for every single img and text you want underneath. Change the `<p>` to a `<ul>` with a `<li>`

Then the jquery code would look like this.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').stop().fadeToggle(400);
    });
});
```

If you would like me to explain the jquery code I would be happy to answer it. Remember that the html is just a change into them into lists. If you don't use any javascript they would just look like lists.

We can use some css to get rid of the decorations that lists have

```
li {
    list-style-type: none
}
```

Comment: what would be the point of adding another unordered list and list item? There's only one name

Comment: @jmore009 in reality there is 'no point' however I find it much easier to work with lists due to the fact that this is similar to a dropdown menu. Usually dropdown menus are located in the navbar and lists are used to create navbars. So its just good practice for that. And my personal preference.

Comment: Yeah but this is already contained in a list. I'm not trying to be rude about it, just pointing out that adding an extra `ul`  is unnecessary extra markup and not good practice. list-items should be used for just that, lists. This is an individual line of text wrapped in a singular list-item. OP's current code structure was just fine

Comment: @jmore009 can't disagree with you. I'll keep that in mind. And don't worry you weren't rude, just pointed out something.

Answer (score 0):

$( document ).ready( function() {

$(".figcaption").hover(function() { $( this ).stop().animate( { opacity:1 }, 700, "easeOutQuad" ); }, function() { $( this ).stop().animate( { opacity:0 }, 700, "easeOutQuad" ); })
});

Comment: What is easeOutQuad, what is .figure caption. And why is the function without any sort of identation. If you are going to answer something answer the question with his examples and make your code easy to read.